# Which reagents can directly oxidize ammonium ion into gaseous dinitrogen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have a simple question. I've looked on the internet and the only thing I found was the [Anammox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anammox) process - *An*aerobic *Amm*onium *Ox*idation.  Wikipedia lists the reaction as:

$$\ce{NH4+} +\ce{NO2-}\rightarrow\ce{N2}+\ce{2H2O}$$

But only a few bactetria perform this process. I am looking for actual laboratory reagents that can oxidize ammonium ion to dinitrogen gas. My professor said that neither $\ce{KMnO4}$ nor $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ can do the oxidation, and that one would have to use bleaching powder or $\ce{XeF2}$ instead. However I could NOT confirm his claim on the internet. Thus, I wish to know a list of such reagents which can do what I wish to. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrite

Comment: @permeakra Thanks for your comment! Though it seems like a special case of the above Anammox process I mentioned above, as it can take place without those nasty bacteria, while the original reactive ions (ammonium and nitrite) remain the same.

Comment: Bromine does that. $\ce{2 NH3 + 3 Br2 -> N2 + 6 HBr}$. Because the $\ce{HBr}$ that is generated reacts with ammonia, some of the ammonia is of course not converted to nitrogen, but to ammonium bromide.

Comment: @user6376297 Wow, that's kinda surprising because among the halogens, generally fluorine is the best oxidizing agent (as it even forms $\ce{XeF6}$). Do fluorine and chlorine also give the same reaction? And what about their elder brother, iodine?

Comment: If by 'surprising' you mean 'hard to believe', I can reassure you: I tried it, and it works. If you mean 'counterintuitive', well, consider that the formation of nitrogen from ammonia probably implies the attack of one nucleophilic nitrogen atom on an electrophilic nitrogen atom, and the detailed mechanism may be very complex. Halogens will usually react with ammonia to give $\ce{X-NH2}$ compounds initially. The properties of X (and sometimes the reaction conditions) will determine what happens next. I suggest you look up the individual reactions in detail if you're interested.

Comment: @user6376297 Yes, I meant the counterintuitive part (English is not my native language :P) Thanks for detailing though!

Comment: You're welcome. One thing that I should mention too is that we don't necessarily want to use the most powerful reagent all the time. On the contrary, the finest chemistry is often the one that manages to strike that very hard to achieve delicate balance between (atom) efficiency and selectivity. In your specific example, nitrogen's highest oxidation state is not $0$, thus using a stronger oxidizing reagent may even be counterproductive, given that you want to stop at that.

Comment: Any reaction of ammonia and halogenes is not advised. Halogennitrides may form, and they are explosive. Halogeneamines are not healthy substances either.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21817/is-there-a-simple-and-inexpensive-way-to-generate-nitrogen-gas

Comment: @permeakra : you're right, bromine+ammonia is not ideal, if the point is to produce nitrogen gas in a controlled, clean way from ammonia. I actually used this reaction to quench traces of bromine I had in some waste, using an excess of ammonia, surely NOT to _make_ nitrogen. Sorry if my post was interpreted that way, I had understood the OP's question to be an academic/theoretical one. Have you got better/safer methods to suggest?

Comment: @NilayGhosh : indeed ( [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen#Production) ). Then it appears the OP is mistaken in thinking that the reaction between ammonium and nitrite can only happen in bacterial processes. Still not entirely safe; [this other Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrite) claims explosions can happen in _solutions_ of ammonium nitrite unless one is carefully controlling the stoichiometry and pH.

Comment: BTW, I'm not convinced that permanganate cannot do anything with ammonium. I know that solid ammonium bichromate and ammonium permanganate do decompose producing dinitrogen. Also, permanganate is used for oxidation of organic amines to produce nitrocompounds, so...